# Opencv 4 Android: Error in Mat() inizialization inside onCreate

Tags: java, android, opencv, oncreate

i wrote a code starting from the camera view tutorial. In the function "onCameraFrame()" I extract ORB features and draw them on the shownFrame. To this end I first declare and initialize both the detector, descriptor as well as the required arrays to handle the keypoints and the descriptors inside this function and all works well.

```
 public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    Mat shownFrame = inputFrame.rgba();

    Mat camDescriptors = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint camKeypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();

    DescriptorExtractor descriptor;


    //Feature detection
    FeatureDetector detector =  FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
    detector.detect(shownFrame, camKeypoints);

    //Feature description
    descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
    descriptor.compute(shownFrame, camKeypoints,camDescriptors);

    //Drawing
    Imgproc.cvtColor(shownFrame, shownFrame, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);
    Features2d.drawKeypoints(shownFrame, camKeypoints, shownFrame, new Scalar(255,0,0,0),Features2d.DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(shownFrame, shownFrame, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2RGBA);

    return shownFrame;
```

but of course it should be better initialize the required objects before this process to save memory and computation. So i declared the detector, descriptor and so on as private variables of the Activity class. Then i've initializated them in the method OnCreate leaving just their use for matching in the onCameraFrame method. But what happens is that an error occur in the first row of onCreate method when i do "camDescriptors = new Mat()", the error is that the method Mat() is not found, and of course the application crashes.

the error message is something like this:
"no implementation found for native Lorg opencv Mat n_Mat: ()"

Comment: Seems OpenCV has not been inited when you new Mat() in onCreate method, where did you init the OpenCV or load the .so libraries?

Comment: as i said, i started from the camera preview tutorial. It uses the opencv Manager and i've no wrote the initialization.... but in the method onCreate there is the initialization of the camera bridge which is an opencv class (CameraBridgeViewBase).

Comment: do you mean this tutorial? http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/technologies/mobile/opencv_tutorial_camera_preview.htm

Comment: maybe i got it... the opencv initialization consists of calling this function   
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback);    but this is wrote in the body of "onResume()" that is called AFTER onCreate... is it right? but if so, why does the initialization of the camera bridge works?

Comment: Yes, I think so. The camera bridge has nothing to do with the native code, so It will work.

Comment: yes is one of the tutorial included in the "samples" directory and seems to be it.

Comment: So you must make sure OpenCV is inited, then `new Mat()`. Maybe the first time the `onCameraFrame` is called.

Comment: i will put the initializations in "onCameraViewStarted" which is called everytime first of the onCameraFrame loop. Could it be a good choice?

Comment: Yes, I think it's better if it will work :)